# MongoDB: Updating a document with existing fields using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am new to mongodb, I am learning from some Udemy courses and I want to know how I can update a document existing field without overwriting it.

I have the following collection with these documents:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8zue.png)

I want to add new `warehouses` in the `"item":"drafts"` within the `stock` field.

What I am trying is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA8av.png)

And giving the output it seems that is working, but when I do again `db.matrices.find()`, what I get is the exactly same output that in the first image.

How can I update it? I have tried also the `update` method, but does not do what I want to do.

Thanks!

PD: I am using linux mint, with mongo v5.0.3, and mongosh v1.1.1

Comment: Would be helpful if you can provide your sample data and expected data in **text** instead of *images*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `aggregate` pipeline, this does not update the document in the DB, it just retrieves the result. starting in Mongo version 4.2+ you can now use an aggregation pipeline ( with some limitations ) to [update a document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  item: "drafts"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      stock: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$stock",
          [
            {
              "warehouse": "A",
              qty: 20
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3efnbtapUT_)

I will just say that this specific update is very simple, there is no need to use an aggregation pipeline for it. a simple use of the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/update/push/) operator in the update field will suffice in a "normal" update:

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  item: "drafts"
},
{
  $push: {
    stock: {
      "warehouse": "A",
      qty: 20
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SxQDbFxnR0Q)

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much! I was searching on the web before posting this, but always pop up the "update" option without the $push operator!