# How to update using existing field in $push

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a JobApplication Schema/model

```js
const applicationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  job: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Job",
    required: true,
    index: true,
    validate: {
      validator: async function(value) {
        const count = await Job.exists({_id: value});
        return count;
      },
      message: "job should be one of the listed one",
    },
  },
  jobApplicant: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "JobApplicant",
    required: true,
    index: true,
    validate: {
      validator: async function(value) {
        const count = await JobApplicant.exists({_id: value});
        const appliedAlready = await JobApplication.exists({
          job: this.job,
          jobApplicant: this.jobApplicant
        });
        return count && appliedAlready == false;
      },
      message: "JobApplicant should be one of the listed one or already Applied",
    },
  },
  phase: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: async function(value) {
        const exist = await JobApplicant.exists({
          _id: this.job,
          "phaseList.phaseName": value
        }, {
          "phaseList.$": 1
        });
        console.log('from phase', exist)
        return exist;
      },
      message: "phase should be one of the listed one",
    }
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: async function(value) {
        const count = await Constent.exists({
          title: 'AP_PH',
          values: {$in: [value]}
        });
        return count;
      },
      message: "status should be one of the listed one",
    },
    index: true,
  },
  comments: [{
    from: {type: String},
    to: {type: String},
    comment: {type: String},
    data: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now()
    }
  }],
  resume: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ResumeCopy',
    validate: {
      validator: async function(value) {
        const count = await Resume.exists({_id: value});
        return count;
      },
      message: "Resume should be one of the listed one",
    }
  },
  quentionList: [{
    questionId: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Question',
      validate: {
        validator: async function(value) {
          const count = await Job.find({
            _id: this.job,
            additionalQuestions: {
              $in: [questionId]
            }
          });
          return count;
        },
        message: "questionId should be one of the listed one",
      },
    },
    answer: String
  }],
  applicationDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  notes: String,
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});
```

I want to push a comment in this array of comment I have used many ways ,one of the way is

```
const documents = await JobApplication.updateMany({
  jobApplicant: {
    $in: jobApplicationIds
  },
  job: req.params.jobId
}, {
  $set: {
    status: req.body.status
  },
  $push: {
    comments: {
      from: "$status",
      to: req.body.status,
      comment: req.body.comment
    }
  }
}, {
  runValidators: true
})
```

but it push value in from as `$status` string ,, i want to get the value of old (before update happened ) status value .

```
const documents = await JobApplication.updateMany({
  jobApplicant: {
    $in: jobApplicationIds
  },
  job: req.params.jobId
}, {
  $set: {
    status: req.body.status
  },
  $push: {
    comments: {
      from: "$status",
      to: req.body.status,
      comment: req.body.comment
    }
  }
}, {
  runValidators: true
})
```

and also tried this

```
db.getCollection("jobapplications").aggregate([{
    $match: {
      _id: new ObjectId('64a52425af1fef519445ff22')
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      comments: {
        $concatArrays: [{
            $ifNull: ["$comments", []]
          },
          ["$phase"]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

but didn't get proper response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: Updating a document with existing fields using aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69789273/mongodb-updating-a-document-with-existing-fields-using-aggregation)